# Symfony getUser type hinting

Tags: symfony, type-hinting

I find it somewhat annoying to have to constantly use @var on getUser. It seems sloppy.

So I was thinking about starting to use this instead

```
<?php

// in the controller
$user = Customer::isCustomer($this->getUser());

// in the entity
/**
 * @param Customer $user
 *
 * @return Customer
 */
public static function isCustomer(Customer $user)
{
    return $user;
}
```

Is this a good idea? Bad idea? Horrible idea?

Comment: By the way, `isCustomer` implies that the return type is boolean, ie, it returns true if `$user` is a customer... so be careful with the function naming.

Answer (score 1):

A type hint is the better option in this case.

Why would you write more code by adding checks manually rather than adding a simple type hint to your param.

Your four lines of codes representing two conditions give exactly the same result as:

```
/**
 * @param Customer|null  $user
 *
 * @return Customer|null
 */
public static function isCustomer(Customer $user = null)
{
    // If $user is null, it works
    // If $user is a Customer instance, it works
    // If it's other, an exception is thrown

    return $user;
}
```

Type hinting optimises and give more readability to a code.
It's a convention in symfony2, php and more.

It's commonly used as a constraint (or contract) with you and your method.

Also, it's the only alternative for an interface or an abstract class to add requirement to a parameter, because they don't have a body, and so cannot write conditions.

**Update**

In SensioLabs Insight, Object type hinting represents a warning using the following message :

> The parameter user, which is an object, should be typehinted.

Because the verb `should` is used, I consider it's not a mandatory requirement, just a very good practice in case of it doesn't cause any problem.

Also, you can use the example you given without making your code horrible.

Comment: While this does not answer me, it's a solid improvement. Thank you!

Comment: I was not sure to see totally the point of your question. Can you help me to understand better ? What do you mean by `@var` ?

Comment: Basically my controllers are plagued with `/* @var Customer $user */` which I am trying to get rid of, 'cause I'm telling the IDE something that (at some point) might not be true.

Comment: Yes. The point is if I don't use them, there's no type awareness in the IDE, I'm trying to find a Better Way (tm)

Comment: use `Type|null` can help, and use `Interface`'s and parent classes as more as possible to make your type hint matching several classes.

Comment: That I can do when I define the methods, Symfony's Controller::getUser returning mixed is the issue.

Comment: I changed my answer.